# Strange error messages in /var/log/apport.log

Tags: session, apport

The log file `/var/log/apport.log`
contains a lot of messages of the form:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 7107) Fri Dec 16 18:58:31 2016: called for pid 7103, signal 5, core limit 0
ERROR: apport (pid 7107) Fri Dec 16 18:58:31 2016: executable: /usr/bin/xfsettingsd (command line "xfsettingsd --display :0.0 --sm-client-id 227270fe4-2f8e-4ec9-a0f8-560f8200286e")
ERROR: apport (pid 7107) Fri Dec 16 18:58:31 2016: gdbus call error: Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
ERROR: apport (pid 7107) Fri Dec 16 18:58:31 2016: debug: session gdbus call: 
ERROR: apport (pid 7107) Fri Dec 16 18:58:31 2016: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
ERROR: apport (pid 7116) Fri Dec 16 18:58:31 2016: another apport instance is already running, aborting
ERROR: apport (pid 7119) Fri Dec 16 18:58:31 2016: another apport instance is already running, aborting
```

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I am not 100% sure what is causing the errors but it looks like your XFCE experienced an issue where it crashed. In the logs we see the signal 5 ([signal man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)) for the pid 7103, and then another pid starts up 7107. For pid 7107 the error looks like it originated from `/usr/bin/xfsettingsd`, that had two other crashes but the log just logged it as: `this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring`. It looks like XFCE tried to start another instance but 7107 did not stop entirely and so it was not able to start again.

I'm not 100% on this so if someone knows more about this then me, please correct me.